# countdown timer with servertime php

Tags: php, countdown, server-side

I want to set up countdown to my store, but countdown date with start and close must assign using php. that means server date of end which i can specify manually and start date will come using php date function..

Can you please give any one advice or link ? Countdown should not take local PC time/date of client.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in general depends on the scale of the time periods. In the store I believe we're talking of pretty long periods to count, such as hours or days.
What I'd suggest in such a case is get the start time from the server (PHP), and start counting on the local machine (JavaScript), every few seconds (minutes?) synching to the remote machine (AJAX). And of course when you reach the target of the time check against the server again.